# How to find the data key on CheckedChanged event of checkbox in ListView in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, checkbox

I am using a list view inside that in item template i am using a label and a checkbox.
I want that whenever user clicks on the check box the value should be updated in a table.i am using a datakeys in listview.on the basis of datakey value should be updated in the table. Query is:

```
string updateQuery = "UPDATE [TABLE] SET [COLUMN] = " + Convert.ToInt32(chk.Checked) + " WHERE PK_ID =" + dataKey + " ";`
```

also i want some help in displaying the result as it is inside the table.means if the value for column in table for a particular pkid is 1 then the checkbox shoul be checked.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvFocusArea" runat="server" DataKeyNames="PK_ID" OnItemDataBound="lvFocusArea_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="1" width="400px">
            <tr style="background-color: #E5E5FE">
                <th align="left">
                    Focus Area
                </th>
                <th>
                    Is Current Focused
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td width="80%">
                <asp:Label ID="lblFocusArea" runat="server" Text=""><%#Eval("FOCUS_AREA_NAME") %></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFocusArea" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkFocusArea_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #EFEFEF">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFocusArea" runat="server" Text=""><%#Eval("FOCUS_AREA_NAME") %></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFocusArea" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkFocusArea_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <td>
            item selected
        </td>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Help me.

Comment: its not mandatory you have to accept if it works else it ok i will delete my answer in that case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out : may help to resolve your issue of geting datakey

```
protected void chkFocusArea_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;  
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)cb.NamingContainer; 
    ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)item ;
    string code = ListView1.DataKeys[dataItem.DisplayIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i am using Visual web developer 2008 express edition there is no such DisplayIndex item is showing in itellisense.

Comment: bro this property is also not availabel

Comment: I would change the last line to: lvFocusArea.DataKeys[dataItem.DisplayIndex]["PK_ID"];

Answer (score 1):

Use Data Binding Expression

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkFocusArea" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("[COLUMN]")  %>' oncheckedchanged="chkFocusArea_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

In your chkFocusArea_CheckedChanged event handler, perform your database insertion and rebind the data.