# How to pass the count of checkbox checked in listview C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, checkbox

Good Afternoon ,
I have collection of checkboxes under Listview .

Can u suggest me how to pass the count of checked and unchecked checkbox items .
Label count has to be updated when checkbox is checked or unchecked .

My code

```
<ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <p style="text-align: left; padding: 3px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title")%>' CssClass="imglbl" /><br />
                            <img src="<%#Eval("ThumbNail")%>" style="vertical-align: middle;" height="120" width="110" id="myimg" title="Click to Play" /><br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblpricetag" Text="Price($):" runat="server" Style="float: left; display: inline; margin-top: 8px;" /><asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Price")%>' CssClass="imgprice" /><br />
                            <br />
                            <%--<input type="checkbox" id="chkaddtocart" value='<%#Eval("id")%>' name="chkaddtocart" onchange="chkonclick(this.checked,this.value);" />Add to Cart--%>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkaddtocart" runat="server" Onclick=function() Text="Add to Cart" />
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

I got it in script but i want it in codebehiend

this is my script code

```
 function chkonclick(o,chkvalue) {
        //alert(o + "," + chkvalue);
        if (o) {
            myitems += 1;
        }
        else {
            if (myitems > 0)
                myitems -= 1;
            else
                myitems = 0;
        }
        myitemslabel = myitems + " items";
        $("#txtitems").val(myitems.toString());
        $("#lblitems").html(myitemslabel);

    }
```

Comment: please add the your asp.net markup code for `txtitems`

Comment: I have this  <input type="text" id="txtitems"/> in header section

Comment: So you want to update `txtitems`? if so your code should work. `Label count has to be updated when checkbox is checked or unchecked ` what is this Label? Please edit your code with those markup

Comment: label count is txtitme am sorry for that

Comment: label count is txtitme am sorry for that .If 2 checkboxes checked count should be 2 .if 1 unchecked count should be 1 .This is what i need Bro

Answer (score 1):

change your checkbox like this

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFocusArea" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkFocusArea_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

You can make use of checkbox change event

```
protected void chkFocusArea_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;  
   //update label count if checkbox is checked
}
```

Comment: Can u suggest me the logic

Comment: @Kailas = you can check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068628/how-to-find-the-data-key-on-checkedchanged-event-of-checkbox-in-listview-in-asp

Comment: Am not passing Information to DB .I want to update a label with how many checkboes are checked and unchecked

Comment: @PranayRana saras answer chhu

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a name for the checkbox as test
    var list=input[name=test]
    var count = 0;
    var total = 0;
    $(list).each(function() {
    if(this.checked) count++;
    total++;
    });

you can use these two variables for displaying what you want.